# C++ errors for C code

Tags: c, compiler-errors

**2nd EDIT**:

Thank you guys for the help so far!!! I have corrected everything in terms of plain c as that is what my assignment has to be written in. Obviously, my knowledge of C is terrible. I am literally teaching myself C as I write this, but using all of my c++ knowledge to do so. Hence my confusion of the language literals. I am still having issues with my firstCheck() function though. I will explain directly below with my current code.

The firstCheck() function is not working like it should. In readFile() function I have successfully split the text from a given file into  an array line by line.
Then firstCheck() should take that array "myString" and read the first string up until a " " occurs (basically the first word/character/etc.) so that I can evaluate it.

Updated Assem.c

```
#include "assem.h"

int readFile(FILE *file, struct assem *item) 
{
size_t i =0;
item->counter = 0;                                                                      //this is sort of the constructor, if you will. 
size_t maxLines = sizeof item->myLines / sizeof *item->myLines;
                                                                                        //breaks down text file into line by line 
while(i < maxLines && fgets(item->myString, sizeof item->myString, file))               //and stores them into "myLines array"
    {
        item->myLines[i] = strdup(item->myString);
        i++;
        item->counter++;
    }   

return 0;
}

void printFile(struct assem item)                                               //just printing things..prints it with a new line in front
{
            printf("\n");
    for(int s = 0; s < item.counter; s++)
        {
            printf("%s\n", item.myLines[s]);
        }
            printf("\n");
}

int firstCheck(struct assem item)               
{
    char *myWord [7] = {NULL};

    for(int s = 0; s < item.counter; s++)   
        {
        while(strcmp( fgets( item.myString, sizeof item.myString, stdin ), " " ) != 0 )         
            {
                myWord[s] = strdup(item.myLines[s]);
            }           
        }

        for(int s = 0; s < item.counter; s++)
        {
            printf("%s\n", myWord[s]);
        }

return 0;       
}
```

Updated "assem.h"

```
#include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

struct assem
        {
                char myString[101];                     //buffer
                char *myLines[20];                      //this will store the lines from a text file..up to 20 lines
                int counter;                            //counter for number of lines
                                                        //printing stuff...prints file directly from whats STORED IN THE ARRAY

        };

        int readFile(FILE *FileToBeRead, struct assem *item);       //takes in the file that needs to be read and splits it into lines
        int firstCheck(struct assem item);
        void printFile(struct assem item);
```

Updated "main.c"

```
#include "Assem.c"

    int main()
    {
        struct assem test;
        FILE *mips;
        mips = fopen("/home/rpf0024/cse2610/Program1/mips.asm", "r");
        readFile(mips, &test);
        printFile(test);
        firstCheck(test);
        fclose(mips);
        return 0;
    }
```

*1st EDIT OLD*:
I am currently writing some code that is getting errors but Im not sure how to fix them. Any explanation for these?
The errors are within my firstCheck() function which attempts to read a string up until the first ' ' character in *myLines[] array. Basically, I am trying to read the first word up until a space occurs, store it in another array so that I can evaluate it.

Here are the following errors:
Errors are associated with firstCheck() function all the way at the bottom of my .c file..I have the line numbers commented.

> Assem.c:35:31: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and
>   integer [-fpermissive] Assem.c:37:31: error: cannot convert ‘char**’
>   to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘char* strdup(const char*)

.c file

```
#include "assem.h"

int assem::readFile(FILE *file) 
{
int i =0;
counter = 0;                                            //this is sort of the constructor, if you will. 
                                                        //breaks down text file into line by line 
while(fgets(myString, 101, file) != NULL)               //and stores them into "myLines array"
    {
        myLines[i] = strdup(myString);
        i++;
        counter++;
    }   

return 0;
}

void assem::printFile()                 //just printing things..prints it with a new line in front
{
            printf("\n");
    for(int s = 0; s < counter; s++)
        {
            printf("%s\n", *(myLines+s));
        }
            printf("\n");
}

int assem::firstCheck()                 
{
    char *myWord [7];

    for(int s = 0; s < counter; s++)        //33
        {
        while(gets(*(myLines+s)) != ' ')    //35            
            {
                myWord[s] = strdup(myLines); //37
            }           
        }
return 0;       
}
```

.h file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

class assem
{

    public:
        char myString[101];                     //buffer
        char *myLines[20];                      //this will store the lines from a text file..up to 20 lines
        int counter;                            //counter for number of lines
        int readFile(FILE *FileToBeRead);       //takes in the file that needs to be read and splits it into lines
        int firstCheck();
        void printFile();                       //printing stuff...prints file directly from whats STORED IN THE ARRAY

};
```

Comment: Since when `class` keyword becomes part of C?

Comment: Do you force C++ compilation with `-x c++` or some IDE option?

Comment: I am using g++...is that not right?

Comment: g++ is for C++. gcc is for C. Usually.

Comment: If you're using g++, and use C++ keywords (`class`, `public`) in your code, then your code is C++, not C. The fact that you use C strings instead of std::strings does not change this fact. You should probably edit your question and your tags to include C++ instead of C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to decide whether you're writing C *or* C++.  C does not support classes, and you should not use C-style strings, I/O, and memory management routines in C++ code.  Mixing elements of the two languages is a recipe for heartburn.

C and C++ are completely different languages that happen to share a lot of syntax and semantics, and a well-written C program doesn't look or behave much like a well-written C++ program.

Now that the obligatory rant is out of the way, your two main type errors are as follows:

```
while(gets(*(myLines+s)) != ' ')
```

`gets` (which you should ***never*** ***never*** ***never*** use in either C or C++ ***for any reason***) returns a value of type `char *`, but the character literal `' '` has type `char` (in C++; in C, it has type `int`).  `char` and `char *` are different, *incompatible* types, and you cannot do comparisons between them.

Your other type error is

```
 myWord[s] = strdup(myLines);
```

`myLines` is an *array* of `char *`, which in this context "decays" to type `char **`.  `strdup` expects an argument of type `char *`, hence the error.  You need to pass a specific element of the array to `strdup`:

```
myWord[s] = strdup( myLines[s] );
```

Additionally, you cannot compare C-style strings using the `==` or `!=` operators; you must use a library function like `strcmp`, such as

```
while ( strcmp( buffer, " " ) != 0 )
  ...
```

Note that we're doing the comparison against the *string* literal `" "` instead of the *character* literal `' '`.

If you want to write *C code*, then you need to change `assem` from a `class` to a `struct`, and move the function delcarations outside of the `struct` definition, and pass the struct type as an argument to the functions:

```
/**
 * .h file
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct assem
{
    char myString[101]; 
    char *myLines[20]; 
    int counter;                            
};

int readFile(FILE *FileToBeRead, struct assem *item );       
int firstCheck( struct assem item );
void printFile( struct assem item);
```

Then you need to remove the `assem::` prefix from your function definitions and use the `struct assem` argument:

```
int readFile(FILE *file, struct assem *item) 
{
  size_t i = 0;
  item->counter = 0;

  /**
   * get the number of array elements in item->myLines
   */
  size_t maxLines = sizeof item->myLines / sizeof *item->myLines;

  while( i < maxLines && fgets( item->myString, sizeof item->myString, file ) ) 
  {
    item->myLines[i] = strdup(item->myString);
    i++;
    item->counter++;
  }   

  return 0;
}

void printFile( struct assem item ) 
{
  printf("\n");
  for(int s = 0; s < item.counter; s++)
  {
      printf("%s\n", item.myLines[s])); // use subscript notation; it's 
                                        // easier on the eyes
  }
  printf("\n");
}

int firstCheck( struct assem item )                 
{
  char *myWord [7] = {NULL};

  for(int s = 0; s < item.counter; s++)        
  {
    /**
     * In your original code, you were overwriting the myLines array,
     * which contained what you read from the input file; I'm not sure
     * you want to do that here, so I'm using myString instead.
     */
    while( strcmp( fgets( item.myString, sizeof item.myString, stdin ), " " ) != 0 ) 
    {                                                        
      myWord[s] = strdup(item.myString); 
    }           
  }

  /**
   * At this point, you've dynamically allocated memory for the elements
   * of the myWords array, but you aren't using the array outside of this
   * function and you aren't freeing that memory when you're done, meaning
   * you have a memory leak.
   *
   * If they myWords array doesn't need to exist outside of this function,
   * then you need to free each element before exiting.
   */
  return 0;       
}
```

and then save all that as a **.c** file and compile it with a **C compiler** such as `gcc`.

If you want to write *C++ code*, then you should use the `fstream`, `string`, and `vector` types instead of `FILE` and array types, and you should take advantage of C++ features like the `std::copy` function template and stream iterators:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

class assem
{
  public:

    // don't need the temporary myString buffer

    std::vector< std::string > myLines;

    // since vectors know how big they are, you don't need a separate
    // counter attribute.

    int readFile( std::istream& fileToBeRead );
    int firstCheck( );
    int printFile( );
};

int assem::readFile( std::istream& fileToBeRead )
{
  /**
   * Use the copy function template with a stream iterator to 
   * read the input file into your myLines vector
   */
  std::copy( 
    std::istream_iterator<std::string>( fileToBeRead ), // start 
    std::istream_iterator<std::string>( ),              // end
    back_inserter( myLines )                            // destination
  );
  return 0;
}

void assem::printFile( )
{
  /**
   * Use the same copy method to write each string in the myLines vector
   * to standard output (again using a stream iterator), separated by 
   * newlines.  
   */
  std::cout << std::endl;  // write the leading newline
  std::copy(
    myLines.begin(),                                          // start
    myLines.end(),                                            // end
    std::ostream_iterator< std::string >( std::cout, "\n" )   // destination
  );
}

int assem::checkFirst( )
{
  std::vector< std::string > myWords;

  for ( std::vector::size_type s = 0; s < myLines.size(); s++ )
    std::cin >> myWords;

  return 0;
}

int main( void )
{
  std::ifstream fileToBeRead( "myfile.txt" ); // or whatever its name is
  if ( fileToBeRead )
  {
    assem myAssem;
    myAssem.readFile( fileToBeRead );
    fileToBeRead.close();
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

then save that as a **.cpp** file and compile it with a **C++ compiler**, such as `g++`.  Notice that with the C++ code you don't need to muck with `strdup` or worry about fixed array sizes, making the code a bit cleaner.

There are other issues with some of the program logic (what are the return values of `readFile` and `checkFirst` going to be used for, and is `0` the right value for that purpose), but this should at least get you on the right track.

Hopefully.

**EDIT**

I realized the logic in the C++ `checkFirst` routine is not a correct translation of your original code.  I know I said you shouldn't mix C-style strings and I/O in C++ code, but sometimes you don't have a choice.  Here's something that should be similar:

```
#include <cstring>         // C++ header file for C-style string routines
... 
char buf[N];               // N is large enough for your input plus 0 terminator
while ( std::cin.get( buf, sizeof buf ) && std::strcmp( buf, " " ) != 0 )
  myWords.push_back ( std::string( buf ) );
```

Comment: Thanks John. This really helped me out a lot. I have corrected everything in terms of plain c as that is what my assignment has to be written in. Obviously, my knowledge of C is terrible. I am literally teaching myself C as I write this, but using all c++ knowledge to do so. Hence my confusion of the language literals. I am still having issues with my firstCheck() function tho. I will post my issue in a new comment

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the *evilness* of [`gets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/gets), the below line

```
 while(gets(*(myLines+s)) != ' ')
```

is erroneous and reason for the first error. `gets()` returns a `char *` and you're comparing that with a *space*, a `char`. It's wrong.

Suggestion: Use `fgets()`. You can use something like

```
while (fgets(string, SIZE, stdin))
```

which checks for the return value of [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) against NULL, the failure indicator.

The other error, I believe is because of trying to mix up `C` and `C++`. Re-write the same code in standard `C` syntax, compiler with a C compiler and you'll be good to go.

Comment: I failed to mention that I have already iterated through my file to break the all of the text into lines...the purpose is to assess a line of text at a time which i will do traversing string by string as i have to evaluate the first word of each line.